# extract data from multiple places with regex

Tags: php, html, regex

I have some html code and I want to get two things from it.

Here is a bit of the code (the rest is just the same)
`<a href="http://url.com/dir?get" target="_blank"><strong>lorem.ipsum</strong></a>
</td>
<td align="center">
2011-02-27<br />14:19:18</td>
<td style="padding: 0px" align="center">
<a href="http://url.com/dir?get=1234"><strong>Lorem</strong></a>
</td>
<td align="center" id="vote_10213">
<strong>2</strong></a><br /><a class="sublink" href="#" onclick="return requestvote(10213)"><strong>[Add&nbsp;vote]</strong></a></td>`

And from this I want to extract lorem.ipsum between the strong tags and the number in the requestvote().

This is what I have:

```
/_blank"><strong>([^<]+)<\/strong>(.*)requestvote\(([^\']+)\)/s
```

But it takes everything in between too. Which I don't want.
I use php:

```
preg_match_all('/_blank"><strong>([^<]+)<\/strong>(.*)requestvote\(([^\']+)\)/s', $response, $match);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost right:

```
preg_match_all('/_blank"><strong>(.*?)<\/strong>.*?requestvote\((.*?)\)/s', $response, $match);
```